# Angular 2 - Promise chaining - promise not getting called

Tags: angular, resolver

I use a resolver and I chain promises but I call a service that also returns a promise, and I cant figure how to use it in my chaining

the body of the second function is never called

```
public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> 
{
    return this.translationsService.getTrads()
    .then(function(response:Response)
    {
        this.coreService.trads=response.json(); <<<< it gets to forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior function and code stops
```

this is how my service function is implemented

```
getTrads() {
    if (this.trads) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(this.trads);
        });
    } else {
        return this.http.get(.....).toPromise();
    }
}
```

I have the feeling I do it wrong, but honestly rxjs is really making things complicated

thanks

**solution : I simplified the code , and "this" was undefined so I used =>**

Comment: You break the chain if you don't return. Like: `return resolve(this.translationsService.getTrads());`

Comment: How do you use the `public resolve(route)` function? This looks quite unnecessary complicated for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I use resolve and return tin the second "then"

Comment: You don't need to wrap `getTrads` in a promise - just use `return this.translationsService.getTrads().then(...)`.

Comment: make getTrads() a promise function, then use `then catch` in your public resolve function to wait for the data in then and get errors in catch block

Comment: Well, you could provide some more information. Where is the `response` variable coming from and what does its `json` function do? Do you even use the `tradsPromise`?

Comment: I updated the code, it's really weird, as I debug, response has the trads, but once the trads=response.json() is executed, I end up in a forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior function and everything stops

Comment: ok I found it, this was missing again, I used => instead, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your `getTrads` function returns a promise that resolves either to an array or to a HTTP response. If you want it to resolve to the desired array, you'll have to execute the `response.json()` inside the `getTrads` function:

```
getTrads() {
    if (this.trads) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.trads);
    } else {
        return this.http.get(...).toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: ok.. but it does not solve anything, I once again, end up in forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior and the code stops

Comment: ok I found it, this was missing again, I used => instead, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**getTrads()** function as a Promise 
If data exists, send data to `then` block for the next function, if not send it to the `error` block.

```
getTrads(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (this.trads) {
      resolve(this.trads);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
}
```

**resolve()** function as a Promise 
wait for the data from the getTrads() function and handle the received data or error

```
public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.translationsService
      .getTrads()
      .then(result => {
        // resolve here
        // if you want to check if result is empty, do it here as well
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // reject here
      });
  });
}
```

(what you do with the resolve() function is unclear from your question)

Comment: the problem is that the code stops as I use the trad, I updated my question...also the whole idea of the service is to fetch the trads unless it already has it, so the reject makes no sens here

Comment: ok I found it, this was missing again, I used => instead, thanks for your help

Comment: You were use a `then` block on a function which wasn't a Promise, that's why you couldn't reach the response